# how to compare two wav files?

Tags: java

Let's say, we have taken a mic input (say "hello") and stored it as a wav file. Then we take the same input "hello" from the mic. Now if the two are identical then we trigger an action. So how do we compare and check the raw data of the two inputs?

**Update:** Let's suppose we want to have the exact word being spoken amd not being interested about who said the word since that would prevent making the program/software. User independent. In other words: we need to extarct the exact being spoken from the mic input of the user and then check if it was identical to any of the given predefined commands which will in turn trigger an action.

So in other words we need the followng:

1. extract the exact words spoken by the speaker/user.
2. compare/check if the word spoken by the user is same or identical to any of the words stored predefined.

So how do we get about our business?

Comment: do you mean the exact same input or just somebody saying the same word?

Comment: I don't think that's easy to do. Like to see the answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Simple comparison of WAV files is not going to work.  What you need is some kind of voice print software.  But most of the Java speech processing software out there seems to be more focused on speech recognition (figuring out what was said) than on voice prints (who said it).